# ng facebook with facebook comments

Tags: facebook, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments, angularjs-service

I am using [ng-Facebook](https://github.com/GoDisco/ngFacebook) service in my angular web app. I want to include a Facebook comments plugin. So, I have copied the code in the Facebook plugin with the Javascript SDK. I can see the comments in my page but the `ng-Facebook` service is not working.

I am getting this error:

```
FB.init has already been called - this could indicate a problem sdk.js:54
Uncaught Error: invalid version specified  sdk.js:85
```

The code is in a plunker[link](http://plnkr.co/edit/oEeKCKL13H8aNP7lHeCd)

How is the service not working but I can still see the comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know did you solved your issue but facebook changed their javascript-sdk code. I got same error with you and my javascript code was like this;

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
        status: true,  
        cookie: true,  
        oauth: true,  
        xfbml: true
    });
};
(function (d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

And I changed it like this. Then error gone.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&appId=xxxxxxxxxxxx&version=v2.0";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
 }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the ngFacebook service what Graph api version you want to use:

```
app.config(function($facebookProvider) {
   $facebookProvider.setCustomInit({
     version    : 'v1.0'
   });
});
```